# Cloud functions with typescript, how to define shape of snapshot data?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I ran into issues when using typescript with firebase functions, particularly when I grab values from `snapshot.data()`

[image]

`snapshot` itself is typed with firebase by default, but how do I specify shape of `data()` that it returns?

By default `snapshot.data()` has type `DocumentData | undefined`, this comes from firebase, I need to change this to be my interface for this particular data somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple choices for syntax:

```
interface Foo {
    a: string
    b: number
}

const foo1 = snapshot.data() as Foo  // cast it
const foo2 = <Foo> snapshot.data()   // also cast it
```

Using either on of those, you can use object destructuring to get its fields into variables, as your answer shows:

```
const { a, b } = foo1   // automatically assign a and b
```

And you can redefine the local variables if needed:

```
const { a: my_a, b: my_b } = foo1   // assigns my_a and my_b instead
```

This is all purely TypeScript and really has nothing to do with the database API.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone stumbling across same issue, solution is as follows

```
interfacse ICharacterData = {
   username: string,
   race: string,
   skinTone: string,
   gender: string
}
```

And to apply this on top of snapshot data

```
const { username, race, skinTone, gender } = <ICharacterData>snapshot.data()
```